# decltype, result_of, or typeof?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

I have:

```
class A {
public:
    B           toCPD() const;
```

And:

```
template<typename T>
class Ev {
public:
    typedef result_of(T::toCPD()) D;
```

After instantiating `Ev<A>`, the compiler says:

meta.h:12: error: 'T::toCPD' is not a type

neither decltype nor typeof work either.

Comment: For general interest, it's worth noting that C++0x allows the same for nonstatic *data* members. You *can* do for example `struct A { int a; }; decltype(A::a * 3) b = 0;` already in GCC4.5. You can do anything with non-static data-members as long as it happens in an unevaluated operand in C++0x.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since whatever result you obtain depends on the template parameter, `typedef typename` is necessary.

`decltype` is a standard C++11 feature. It is an "operator" which takes an expression and returns a type.

```
typedef typename decltype( T().toCPD() ) D; // can't use T:: as it's nonstatic
```

If `T()` isn't a valid (`T` not default-constructible) you will want `declval` which is a function that takes a type and returns a meaningless, invalid value of that type. `declval` can only be used in unevaluated contexts such as `decltype`.

```
typedef typename decltype( std::declval<T>().toCPD() ) D;
```

Before C++11, `decltype` was a non-standard extension by Microsoft's MSVC compiler. Its behavior might have been changed slightly by standardization.

---

`typeof` is GCC's equivalent pre-C++11 extension like `decltype`, which was also cloned in other compilers. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) is its documentation from GCC. That page provides no comparison between the features, but it notes that `typeof` must be called `__typeof__` when using a standard mode (`-std=c++YY`, which you should **always** do), and it is available in C as well as C++.

For the sake of C compatibility, `__typeof__` will not resolve a reference type from a glvalue expression. So, it's really only suitable for C. This probably explains why the C++ feature didn't inherit the more self-explanatory name: GNU was unwilling to sacrifice backward compatibility, whereas Microsoft cares less about C and perhaps needed fewer changes.

---

`result_of` is a C++11 metafunction (previously standardized in the ISO TR1 library from 2006). It is a template which takes a callable type (such as a function `int(void)`, function pointer `int(*)(void)`, functor class implementing `operator()`, or pointer-to-member-function `&T::toCPD`) and an argument type-list for that type, and provides the return type if the call would work.

To use `result_of` with a pointer to member function, you must include the parent object type in the argument list as a surrogate for `this`.

```
typedef typename std::result_of< decltype( & T::toCPD ) ( T * ) >::type D;
```

This is very brittle, though, because `&T::toCPD` cannot be resolved if there's any overloading, such as a non-const version. This is true despite the fact that `T *` or `T const *` must be explicitly written out! In most cases, you're better off with `decltype` and `declval`.

Comment: There are no special member function types. The type of a member function is a normal function type. For instance member function pointers are member pointers to normal function types: `identity<void()>::type A::*` is equivalent to `void(A::*)()`. You cannot pass a member pointer type to `result_of`. In particular, `result_of<>::type` is specified as `decltype(declval<Fn>()(declval<ArgTypes>()...))` with `Fn` being the function type/function-object type or reference to it passed.

Comment: GCC sometimes outputs the "type" `void(T::)()` or similar for a function of type `void()` in class `T`. But such a type does not exist - it's just implementation details bubbling up.

Comment: Actually, having had a closer look, it's more like `result_if<Fn(Args)>` . So, `Fn` cannot be a function type (the type-id would specify a function returning a function). `Fn` has to be a reference to function or reference or direct type of a function object. And `Args` the arguments it's called with.

Comment: @litb: Thanks! It was hard to figure out what `result_of` is supposed to do because I can't find a single working case for GCC 4.5. Is it supposed to be possible to remove the pointer from a ptmf type and obtain a function type? If not, isn't that a hole in the library? It's easy enough to implement!

Comment: i can't seem to find a ready made standard template for that. As a work-around you could do `typedef typename result_of<decltype(mem_fn(&T::toCPD))()>::type`, i think, but i think it's ugly :)

Answer (score 3):

result_of is not a function neither an operator. result_of is a meta-function having a function as **template** parameter and setting the result type on the member type

```
typedef typename result_of<T::toCPD()>::type D;
```

Comment: It is never valid to call a function inside a template argument.

Comment: It looks like decltype should have worked though. Unless of course it's not supported in the OP's compiler

Comment: What's the header for result_of?

Comment: @jalf: `decltype` didn't work because he attemped to call a nonstatic function using `::`. See my answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: ah right, guess I should have actually read the code properly. ;)