# Build c++0x features with Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation, c++11

When build with Eclipse get warnings and errors about c++0x keywords. Example:

> identifier ‘decltype’ will become a keyword in C++0x

How to workaround it?

EDIT:

> Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Discovery options->GCC C++
>   Compiler->Compiler Invocation Arguments->[-E -P -v -dD
>   ${plugin_state_location}/specs.c --std=gnu++0x]

but it hasnt effect, intresting, even if put there empty string it will try to compile with the same errors. Dont know for what this parameter needed(

Comment: Are you actually trying to compile with C++11?

Comment: what toolchain are you using gcc? if so you need to pass a flag to enable the c++0x features. -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

Comment: @ted, Current toolchain: Linux GCC.

Comment: _decltype is a C++0x extension which isn't yet fully supported by GCC. It is an operator which takes an expression and returns a type._ i took this from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763824/decltype-result-of-or-typeof trying to see if it is outdated

Comment: According to this http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html it should be implemented in gcc >= 4.3 (see _Declared type of an expression_)

Comment: I am wondering about some of the parameters though,
i.e. _-E     Stop after the preprocessing stage;  do  not  run  the  compiler proper.   The  output is preprocessed source code, which is sent to the standard output._ (from man gcc) the question is can you try with onyl one cpp file and compile it directly from a shell? `g++ main.cpp -o main -std=c++0x` should do however i cant try it, to lazy to brin up linux on the universities box. This would determine if the problem originates from exclipse not passing the parameters right.

Comment: I actually tried to launch eclipse on the unis box, but they dont have gcc installed. However the Warnings indicate this `Description Resource Path Location Type
Error launching external scanner info generator (g++ -E -P -v -dD C:/***/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp) demo [Discovery Options]`. this hints that you are only changing the flags for the IDE-Autocomplete or something like that, not for the actual compilation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Project -> Properties -> C++-Build[Settings] -> G++Compiler[miscellanous] -> Other flags

Add "-std=c++0x" there.