# Using the return type of a functor to declare return type of a template method, without decltype

Tags: c++, templates, generics, functor

I would like to avoid the need to specify the return type when calling a template member function.  The 'decltype' keyword combined with 'auto' can accomplish this, but unfortunately we do not have a C++11 compiler for all the platforms we need to support.  Qualifying the template method application with a type also works, but requires the caller to... qualify the template method with a type.

Is the following possible, with some template magic?  Does boost 1.48 provide any help here?

Our actual code is leveraging boost::thread, boost::packaged_task, and boost::unique_future, but here is a contrived example:

```
#include <functional>

#ifdef WONT_COMPILE
struct WrapNoDecltype
{
    WrapNoDecltype() {}

    template<typename F>
    std::result_of<F>::type // warning: 'std::result_of<_Fty>::type' : dependent name is not a type
    operator()(const F& f)
    {
        setup();
        std::result_of<F>::type result = f();
        teardown();

        return result;
    }

    void setup() { }
    void teardown() { }
};
#endif

struct Wrap
{
    Wrap() {}

    template<typename F>
    auto operator()(const F& f) -> decltype(f())
    {
        setup();
        typename std::result_of<F()>::type result = f();
        teardown();

        return result;
    }

    void setup() { }
    void teardown() { }
};

struct WrapWithReturnType
{
    WrapWithReturnType() {}

    template<typename RetType>
    RetType
    apply(const std::function<RetType(void)>& f)
    {
        setup();
        RetType result = f();
        teardown();

        return result;
    }

    void setup() { }
    void teardown() { }
};

int answer()
{
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    Wrap w;
    WrapWithReturnType wwr;
#ifdef WONT_COMPILE
    WrapNoDecltype wna;
#endif

    int i = w(answer);
    int j = wwr.apply<int>(answer);
#ifdef WONT_COMPILE
    int k = wna(answer);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll need a `typename` to avoid the warning (which should even be an error), like `typename std::result_of<F>::type`.

Comment: @DyP wrong question? That question doesn't say that, as far as I can tell. It says that `std::result_of` works on types, not function instances, which is distinct from what you are saying...

Comment: @Yakk ?? There's a comment in the OP's code stating there's a warning, and in the `main` function a non-member function is passed to the `operator ()`, therefore `std::result_of` is instantiated using the type of the non-member function

Comment: @Yakk or do you mean my reference? Well the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11472253/420683) states that `std::result_of` doesn't work on non-member functions (functions' types); the OP of that question has a similar problem.

Comment: @DyP You appear to be misreading the answer.  It states it doesn't work on *instances* of functions.  It states it works on *types* of functions.

Comment: @Yakk For `template <class Fn, class... ArgTypes> struct result_of<Fn(ArgTypes...)>;`: "If the expression `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed"; see [meta.trans.other]

Comment: @DyP ah, I see my error!  Still, it works fine on function pointer types.  Just not on instances.

Comment: While the example is using C++11 constructs, do keep in mind I'm looking for an answer that works on earlier C++ compilers (e.g., VS2005 and GCC 4.2)...

Comment: Boost works with VC8 and gcc 4.2.1, so `boost::result_of` and `boost::decay` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct WrapNoDecltype
{
    WrapNoDecltype() {}

    // version for function references
    template < typename Res >
    Res operator()( Res(&f)() )
    {
        setup();
        Res result = f();
        teardown();

        return result;
    }

    // version for everything
    template < typename T >
    typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<T>::type ()>::type
    operator()( T const& f )
    {
        setup();
        typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<T>::type ()>::type result = f();
        teardown();

        return result;
    }

    void setup() { }
    void teardown() { }
};
```

As [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk) pointed out, by incorporating `decay`, the second version always works. The first version is much simpler but only works when passing function references.

Of course, you can also use `boost::result_of` or `std::tr1::result_of`.

Comment: `std::result_of<T()>` doesn't use a default constructor. `T()` is not a value but a function type. `result_of` uses `declval` to obtain a value, so the default constructor problem does not occur.

Comment: If `f` is a function, then `typename std::result_of<T()>::type operator()( T const& f )` returns the type of a function that returns `f`, not the type of a function that returns `f()`...

Comment: @Yakk if `f` is a function, the first version should be called because it is more specialized -- or am I wrong? `result_of<int()>` is ill-formed

Comment: @DyP sorry, misunderstood how to use `std::result_of` on nullary function types!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, if we modify your call to include a `&` operator, the only errors in your original code is the lack of `typename` when talking about dependent types, and the lack of an argument list when calling `std::result_of`:

```
struct WrapNoDecltype
{
  WrapNoDecltype() {}

  template < typename T >
  typename std::result_of<T()>::type operator()( T const &f )
  {
    setup();
    typename std::result_of<T()>::type result = f();
    teardown();

    return result;
  }
};
```

however, `std::result_of` is a C++11 traits class, so if your compiler doesn't support `decltype`, it may not properly support `std::result_of`.

`std::tr1::result_of` may have quirks that prevent the above from working.

In the wild, a use of `std::result_of` on a function pointer type: http://ideone.com/dkGid8

As @DyP has noted, this only works if you call it with `&f` instead of `f`.  To fix this, use `std::decay` like this:

```
struct WrapNoDecltype
{
  WrapNoDecltype() {}

  template < typename T >
  typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<T>::type()>::type
    operator()( T const &f )
  {
    // setup()
    typename std::result_of<typename std::decay<T>::type()>::type
      result = f();
    // teardown()

    return result;
  }
};

int foo() { return 7; }
int main()
{
  WrapNoDecltype test;
  int x = test(foo);
}
```

which turns the function type into a function pointer type.

This is needed because `std::result_of` abuses C++ syntax.  `std::result_of< Func_Type ( Args... ) >` is actually operating on the type of a function that *returns* `Func_Type` and takes `(Args...)`.  It then says "what if we applied `Args...` to `Func_Type`.  This fails to work when `Func_Type` is an actual type of a function, because you aren't allowed to return actual instances of functions.

`std::decay` turns `Func_Type` as the type of a function into a pointer to the same type of function, which is something a function can return.  And you can invoke a pointer to a function just like you invoke an actual function, so no harm there either.

Comment: `std::result_of<int()>::type i;` is ill-formed, that's why it won't work AFAIK.

Comment: @DyP Fixed -- `typedef int(*func)(); std::result_of< func() >::type i;` is well formed.  I misunderstood the `result_of` docs for nullary functions.  Fixed!

Comment: :) a tricky one... a function returning a function pointer.. Though, as you stated, it only works when called via `wna( &answer );` instead of `wna(answer);`

Comment: @DyP `decay`, however, fixes that.

Comment: Nice, +1. I could as well remove my answer now :(

Comment: You might change your first sentence, the OP _IS_ using `answer` and not `&answer`, so `decay` is required.

Comment: @DyP Mayhap the OP doesn't have `decay`, in which your answer still works but mine would require manually writing `decay`, which would be annoying.

Comment: There are nice "possible implementations" on cppreference, also for [`decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay), also see [`boost::decay`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/decay.html)