# Why isn't std::result_of<int(int)>::type valid?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have read the following related questions:

1. [std::result_of simple function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470802/stdresult-of-simple-function)
2. [decltype, result_of, or typeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763824/decltype-result-of-or-typeof)

and [the page on `std::result_of` at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

All of them seem to indicate that I should be able to use:

```
 std::result_of<int(int)>::type v1 = 10;
```

However, when I tried building the following program using g++ 4.9.2

```
#include <type_traits>

int foo()
{
   return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::result_of<int(int)>::type v1 = 10;           // LINE A
    std::result_of<decltype(foo)>::type v2 = 20;      // LINE B
    return 0;
}
```

I get error messages for "LINE A" and "LINE B". The error messages are:

```
socc.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
socc.cc:10:5: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘std::result_of<int(int)>’
     std::result_of<int(int)>::type v1 = 10;
     ^
socc.cc:11:5: error: ‘type’ is not a member of ‘std::result_of<int()>’
     std::result_of<decltype(foo)>::type v2 = 20;
     ^
```

The command I used to compile:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall    socc.cc   -o socc
```

FWIW, using

```
 typename std::result_of<int(int)>::type v1 = 10;
 typename std::result_of<decltype(foo)>::type v2 = 20;
```

didn't make a difference.

It seems that I am failing to understand how `result_of` is supposed to be used.

Can you explain why I am getting the compiler errors?

Comment: Do you mean `result_of<(int(int))(int)>`?

Comment: note that `result_of` changed from C++11 to C++14, can you confirm you are asking about the C++11 version ?

Comment: @KerrekSB, No, I meant `result_of<(int(int))>`. That may be the the missing piece of my understanding of `result_of`. Would you elaborate on that?

Comment: @MattMcNabb, yes, I am using `C++11`.

Comment: I think you would want to mean that, but you cannot say the type of a function that returns a function. The next best thing is `result_of<int(&(int))(int)>`. [Demo](http://ideone.com/KBJW7J).

Comment: @RSahu: Read again: `result_of<F(Args...)>::type` is the type of the result of calling a *callable of type `F`* with the `Args...`. In your demand, `int` is not callable!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As stated in the link you have already posted, the first part of the argument to `result_of` must be a callable type or a reference to a function.

Suppose you have a

```
struct Callable
{
    int operator()(double);
    void operator()(int);
};
```

then `result_of` helps you determining the return type, if you know the type of the arguments. For the example above:

```
result_of<Callable(int)>::type == void    ... per definition
result_of<Callable(double)>::type == int  ... per definition
result_of<Callable(char)>::type == void   ... the int-overload matches better
result_of<Callable(float)>::type == int   ... the double-overload matches better
```

In order to find the return type of the function `foo` you would have to go via a function reference:

```
result_of<decltype(foo)& ()>::type == int
```

But this seems a bit twisted as you could directly write

```
decltype(foo()) == int
```

Answer (score 12):

You seem to assume `std::result_of<R(Args...)>::type` to be simply `R` - that is, the result type of a function having signature `R(Args...)`. But `std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type` is the result of calling an instance of type `F` with arguments of types `Args...`.

So, `std::result_of<int(int)>::type` does not make sense - `int` objects are not callable.

Please, read [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) again :)

Answer (score 3):

To use `result_of`, the type supplied must be a function type where the return type is the type of a [Callable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable) and the parameter list contains the types of the arguments to call it with. `result_of<int(int)>` therefore asks "what type will I get when I call `declval<int>()` with the argument `declval<int>()`". The answer is that there is no type, because `int` is not a function type.

Here's an excerpt from Table 57:

> If the expression `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed when treated as an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), the member typedef type shall name the type `decltype(INVOKE (declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...));` otherwise, there shall be no member `type`

Given the function `foo`, you can use:

```
 std::result_of_t<decltype((foo))()> v1 = 10;
 std::result_of_t<decltype(&foo)()> v2 = 10;
```

Comment: That is starting to make sense :) Given the `foo` in my question why doesn't `result_of<decltype(foo)()>::type` work?

Comment: @RSahu Because that declares a function returning a function, which you can't do. You can do `decltype(foo)&()` or `decltype(foo)*()` instead.

Comment: @RSahu You have two misplaced curly braces.

Comment: It must be one of those days. Thanks for pointing that out :)