# BOOST_AUTO And C++ User Defined Type

Tags: c++, boost, template-meta-programming, typeof

I'm new to BOOST_AUTO and here is a basic question.

I defined my own class and used it with BOOST_AUTO. According to the tutorial:

> If your define your own type, the Typeof Library cannot handle it
>   unless you let it know about this type. You tell the Typeof Library
>   about a type (or template) by the means of "registering" this
>   type/template.

But my code below doesn't register anything and runs correctly in VC++2010. Is this registration really necessary. Did I do anything wrong?

```
#include <boost/typeof/typeof.hpp>
using namespace std;
namespace NS1 {
    struct X {
        X(const X& x){s=x.s+1;}
        X(){s=3;}
        int s;
    };
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    NS1::X x;
    BOOST_AUTO(y,x);

    cout << y.s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> output:4

Comment: It's possible your compiler supports regular `auto`.

Comment: oh yes it does! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293615(v=vs.100).aspx. Does that mean BOOST_AUTO automatically #define to `auto` in VC++2010?

Comment: @JavaMan: It doesn't matter, just use regular `auto`.

Comment: @JavaMan, From what I've seen of Boost, most libraries like this one are pretty good at using a newer feature directly if the compiler supports it.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html):

> The BOOST_AUTO macro emulates the proposed auto keyword in C++.

looking into the code it seems they replace  `BOOST_AUTO` to `BOOST_TYPEOF`.

`typeof` seems to be the old extension name of `decltype` in GCC compilers.
(See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763824/decltype-result-of-or-typeof)). The code of the boost typeof library doesn't use the auto keyword apparantly for msvc (See [here](https://github.com/boostorg/typeof/blob/c394d0a5ae91cb314cb0b57c69a5cc5b18893f6c/include/boost/typeof/msvc/typeof_impl.hpp)).

It seems that at the time of writing this library, there were some compilers who did support the auto keyword while others did not. If you want to compile the code on architectures that don't support this feature, the registration is necessary.

In any case, since C++11 is released for a while by now. Using this library if you compiler already supports the `auto` keyword should be considered bad practise, because this library only exists to emulate the proposed feature.

Except of course you have to compile to C++03 for some reason.